# Adjusting placement of control objects in a row within a panel

Tags: gui-construction

My minimal example

```
Panel[Column[{
   Row[{"Board size: ", InputField[Dynamic[max], Number, FieldSize -> 3],
      Button["Clear Board"]}], "A graphic object which is large enough"}]]
```

evaluates to

[image]

Since I have a large graphic object underneath the first row, there is some space to the right of the "Clear Board" button.  I would like to move the button to the right so that it is flush with the boundary of the panel -- basically the effect of the LaTeX command `\hfill` if I were typesetting.

I have been messing with `Alignment` and `ControlPlacement`, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want to use `Grid`.

#### Code

```
Panel[
 Grid[
  {
    (* The 1st row *)
    {
      Row[{"Board size: ", InputField[Dynamic[max], Number, FieldSize -> 3]}], 
      Button["Clear Board", ImageSize -> All]
    },
    (* The 2nd row *)
    {
      Graphics[Circle[], ImageSize -> 300], SpanFromLeft
    }
  }, Alignment -> {{Left, Right}, Baseline}]
]
```

#### Result

> [image: Output]

#### Few things

1. `SpanFromLeft` is used so that the first column of the second row would occupy the second column too.

   ```
   Grid[{
     {"A", "B"},
     {"C", SpanFromLeft}
    }, Frame -> All, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 36}]
   ```

   > [image: spanfromleft]
2. `Button`'s default `ImageSize` is `Full`, which makes it stretched so that it would fill all cell. So I changed it to `All` which makes its width just enough for the text.

   - `Button[..., ImageSize->Full]` (or the default)

   [image: full]

   - `Button[..., ImageSize->All]`

   [image: all]
3. `Alignment` can be specified in `{horizontal, vertical}` order. Within each, you can specify them for each row / column by giving a list (in this case, `Left` for the first column, `Right` for the second column).

`Grid` has a very rich syntax. The [reference](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Grid.html) is always a good source.

Answer (score 10):

This solution illustrates using `Spacer`. Move the slider to place the button anywhere you want along the width of interface:

```
Manipulate[Panel[Column[{Row[{"Board size: ",InputField[Dynamic[max], Number, 
FieldSize -> 3], Spacer[spacer], Button["Clear Board"]}], Plot[Sin[x], {x, -3, 3}, 
ImageSize -> 400]}]], {{spacer, 100}, 0, 220}, FrameMargins -> 0, Paneled ->False]
```

[image]

This one is good for precise placement inside a `Row`. For cool `Grid` options see @Yu-Sung answer.