# How can I control the controlplacement of Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate

I want to place the `Slider` of manipulate as I want but I can't, help me to get rid of it

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}], {{a, 2, ""}, 1, 4,
ControlPlacement -> Top}, {{b, 0, ""}, 0, 10,   
ControlPlacement -> Bottom}, ContentSize -> 500]
```

Instead of `ControlPlacement -> Top`, `ControlPlacement -> Bottom` I want to use `ControlPlacement -> {Top,Center}` and `ControlPlacement -> {Bottom,Right}` respectively.

Comment: Related question: [(3590)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3590/17).

Comment: `Center` is not valid for `ControlPlacement`. `ControlPlacement -> {Bottom, Right}` means put first control at `Bottom` and second control at `Right`

Comment: @m_goldberg `ControlPlacement -> {Bottom, Right}` means put second control in Bottom right.